# How to access Postgres database within docker-compose

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, containers, cookiecutter

I'm pretty new to Postgres and Docker, but I am building a webapp with Django that runs inside a docker with a postgresql database. I am trying to view my Postgres database via the command prompt or pgweb.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find the database at all, I tried using the postgres psql terminal commands, but my database wasn't listed inside. My question is, how is the postgresql database stored within a docker-compose container. Do I need to go into the container manually and then view the database? My ultimate goal is to be able to see a list of all my tables and data within the postgresql database.

Any documents explaining how the postgresql database interacts with a docker-compose would be appreciated.

Thanks!

I just recently added Pgweb, but that doesn't seem to be working

**Local.YML**

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data_local: {}
  postgres_backup_local: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=vicki
      - USE_DOCKER=yes
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start.sh

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_local:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup_local:/backups
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=vicki

  pgweb:
    container_name: pgweb  
    restart: always  
    image: sosedoff/pgweb
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    links:
      - postgres:postgres  
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

This is the Postgres Terminal psql I am talking about, When I open my terminal and run:

```
postgres@dom-Inspiron-7559:~$ psql
psql (9.3.19)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
postgres=#
```

This list of databases appears, but I don't believe vickibot is the same as vicki.
(I had made two apps with django cookiecutter, one within docker and one not in docker. I believe the one I am using right now is "vicki" that is within a docker container, but again i'm not sure and don't know how to tell what database my models file is referencing. I am wondering if I need to somehow enter the docker container to view the database)

```
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 test1     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 vickibot  | dominic  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the same link: links:
      - postgres:postgres to the django service?

Comment: also "I tried using the postgres psql terminal" which terminal are you referring to? @Zalkota

Comment: Hi Sergiu, I'm not sure what you mean be the links, i tried adding postgres:postgres to "services:" , but that doesn't work. I added more information in regard to the terminal above

Comment: Hi, what i meant was are you able to access your postgres db from within pgweb?

Comment: @Sergiu links are not required on the user defined networks that come with v2+ compose files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To access postgres in the container, run the cli in the scope of the container

```
docker-compose run postgres psql
```

You can also connect to the containers published port, which hasn't been  published in your existing config.

```
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_local:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup_local:/backups
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=vicki
```

Then connect to your published port

```
psql -h localhost -p 5433
```

Comment: Thank you so much Matt! This is what I needed, connecting to the database in the container

Comment: One last question, How do I connect to the pgweb? I can see in my running containers that it is infact running, but when I visit the URL in my internet browser: localhost:8081 I receive an error page.

Comment: I'm trying to run pgweb, so far I've tried to run this command "docker-compose -f local.yml run pgweb --url postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres
" But i'm getting an oci runtime error

Comment: I think the database url should be something like `DATABASE_URL=postgres://vicki:somepass@postgres:5432/somedb`  but an oci error is a bad command.